# MySql Query returns results in Workbench, but not in Flask app

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have a Flask app that is executing an sql query to retrieve a list of parts from a MySql database. My problem is that I am sure I have the SQL query correct, because it works in MySql workbench, but when I run the same query in the app is returns an empty list.

I am fairly new to this so go easy on me.

SQL query:

```
SELECT job_part.*, part.part_name, part.cost
  FROM job_part
  JOIN part ON job_part.part_id = part.part_id
 WHERE job_part.job_id = 5;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mifJB.png)

my Python

```
connection = getCursor()
sql = """SELECT job_part.*, part.part_name, part.cost
           FROM job_part
           JOIN part ON job_part.part_id = part.part_id
           WHERE job_part.job_id = %s;"""
connection.execute(sql, (jobNo,))
partList = connection.fetchall()
connection.close()
print(partList)
```

jobNo is 5 as a str, I have tried converting to int but no difference

I get [] in the terminal

Comment: I linked the wrong screenshot, this was from a similar query. The output from workbench is very similar for this query.

Comment: Your code seems correct, place your code in a `try-except` block to catch any potential errors. It could be failing silently due to an exception during execution.

Comment: Thanks Amit. Have tried this and no errors.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all who offered help. I had been using mysql 8.2 and been getting a version mismatch error in workbench whenever I started it, and had been ignoring it, hadn't caused any obvious problems. In the end uninstalling mysql and workbench and installing v8.0 for both resolved this issue. Lesson leanred.

Answer (score 0):

Try to narrow down the cause of the problem. Could be:

1. a db connection issue, for instance libraries or drivers
2. a problem with the variable string substitution
3. a problem with query column or table aliases (the fact that you are using a * and using the same table name as an alias instead of t1 and t2 which is more common)

I'm leaning for (2). Try to follow these troubleshooting steps: change the query and use a static job_id. If that works, then you know it's got to do with variable substitution.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I have other queries executing successfully so it cant be a connection issue, tried with a static job_id with the same result, tried rewriting with table aliases, same result. This is really doing my head in! lol

Comment: I need more context. So you say that you have other Python+Flask queries retrieving results successfully. What's different from them? Are you closing a session and opening a session each time? Try to write a very simple query to see if it gets something at all, eg: select count(*) as cnt from job_part.